# Access to the coordinates of a NetCDF file

Tags: python, coordinates, netcdf, rioxarray, variables

I started working with NetCDF files recently.

I'm working with projected Surge Levels; Data is stored as `filename.nc` files at Copernicus. [This is the file](https://mega.nz/file/3GhlmAjD#ABf_DzJFF99nMmpKVoytnom0e7x6hA9nBKGSfmkMDX4). I got it using an API from [their website](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-water-level-change-indicators-cmip6?tab=form).

After downloading the .nc file, I wanted to convert it to a single-band, GeoTIFF raster file using Python. Thus I tried using [this script](https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/5029956-how-to-convert-netcdf-to-geotiff) from Copernicus Help. But I run into a problem because I can't reproduce the part of the script that sets the spatial dimensions: `nc_file.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='lon', y_dim='lat')`

At first I thought it was just because my coordinates are called differently than those of the .nc file of the example script. So I inspect my nc file and observe that, in the [example script](https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/5029956-how-to-convert-netcdf-to-geotiff) the structure of the data includes 4 coordinates (`depth`, `lon`, `time`, `lat`) and 2 data variables (`thetao` and `bottomT`):

[image]

Instead, my file seems to have the coordinates named as `station_x_coordinate` and `station_y_coordinate`:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                  (stations: 43119)
Coordinates:
  * stations                 (stations) uint16 0 1 2 3 ... 43731 43732 43733
    station_x_coordinate     (stations) float64 ...
    station_y_coordinate     (stations) float64 ...
Data variables:
    return_mean_surge_level  (stations) float64 ...
Attributes: (12/34)
    Conventions:                   CF-1.6
    featureType:                   timeSeries
    id:                            GTSMv3_extreme_value_analysis
    naming_authority:              https://deltares.nl/en
    Metadata_Conventions:          Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0
    title:                         relative change in return values for surge...
    ...                            ...
    geospatial_vertical_max:       18.564
    geospatial_vertical_units:     m
    geospatial_vertical_positive:  up
    time_coverage_start:           1985
    time_coverage_end:             2050
    experiment:                    highres-future
```

As you can see, the coordinates are supposed to be named `station_x_coordinate` and `station_y_coordinate`. However, apparently they are not treated as **dimension coordinates** by xarrays (according to [xarrays docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#coordinates)).
Thus, I can't continue with [the script to get a GeoTIFF from the NetCDF](https://help.marine.copernicus.eu/en/articles/5029956-how-to-convert-netcdf-to-geotiff) file because I get stuck when I try set the spatial dimensions in Python ([rio library](https://pypi.org/project/rio/)):

```
file_nc.rio.set_spatial_dims( x_dim = 'station_x_coordinate',
                              y_dim = 'station_y_coordinate')
```

I assume that the fact that `station_x_coordinate` and `station_x_coordinate` are not **dimension coordinates** is the reason why I get the following error message:
`MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension (station_x_coordinate) not found. Data variable: return_mean_surge_level`

Is there a way to overcome this, eg. can I turn `station_x_coordinate` and `station_y_coordinate` into real **dimension coordinates** to use them as indicated in the script?

My objective is to convert the NetCDF file into a GeoTIFF, using Python. What are my options at this point?

---

This is the output from Panoply:

```
File "CMCC-CM2-VHR4_future_surge_relative-change_2021-2050_rp50_best-fit_v1.nc"
File type: Hierarchical Data Format, version 5
 
netcdf file:/data/CMCC-CM2-VHR4_future_surge_relative-change_2021-2050_rp50_best-fit_v1.nc {
  dimensions:
    stations = 43119;
  variables:
    double return_mean_surge_level(stations=43119);
      :_FillValue = NaN; // double
      :short_name = "return_mean_surge_level";
      :long_name = "relative change from 2021-2050 minus 1985-2014 in mean fit return surge levels for rp50";
      :units = "m";
      :coordinates = "station_x_coordinate station_y_coordinate";

    ushort stations(stations=43119);

    double station_x_coordinate(stations=43119);
      :_FillValue = NaN; // double
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :short_name = "longitude";
      :long_name = "longitude";
      :crs = "EPSG:4326";

    double station_y_coordinate(stations=43119);
      :_FillValue = NaN; // double
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :short_name = "latitude";
      :long_name = "latitude";
      :crs = "EPSG:4326";

  // global attributes:
  :Conventions = "CF-1.6";
  :featureType = "timeSeries";
  :id = "GTSMv3_extreme_value_analysis";
  :naming_authority = "https://deltares.nl/en";
  :Metadata_Conventions = "Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0";
  :title = "relative change in return values for surge levels";
  :summary = "Dataset with return values for surge levels. Produced with the Global Tide and Surge Model (GTSM) version 3.0 forced with winds and sea surface pressure from CMCC-CM2-VHR4 dataset for the period 2021-2050. The exceedance probabilities are based on fitting a Generalized Pareto distribution to the independent peaks that exceeed the 99th percentile. The 5-95th percentile confidence bounds are based on bootstrapping.";
  :history = "This is version 1 of the dataset";
  :date_created = "2021-06-24 11:57:27.465279 UTC";
  :project = "GTSMip and C3S_435_Lot8 Deltares";
  :acknowledgment = "The development of this dataset was financed with Deltares Strategic Research Program. Additional funding was received by Contract C3S_435_Lot8 Deltares";
  :contact = "Please contact Copernicus User Support on the Copernicus Climate Change Service website (https://climate.copernicus.eu/).";
  :license = "Copernicus Products License";
  :institution = "Deltares, IHE Delft, Vrije Universiteit Amsterdam";
  :sea_name = "global";
  :source = "GTSMv3";
  :keywords = "sea-level rise; climate change; water level; climate; tides; hydrography; global tide and surge model;";
  :keywords_vocabulary = "http://www.eionet.europa.eu/gemet";
  :standard_name_vocabulary = "";
  :geospatial_lat_min = "-84.712";
  :geospatial_lat_max = "83.65";
  :geospatial_lon_min = "-179.985";
  :geospatial_lon_max = "179.956";
  :geospatial_lat_units = "degrees_north";
  :geospatial_lat_resolution = "point";
  :geospatial_lon_units = "degrees_east";
  :geospatial_lon_resolution = "point";
  :geospatial_vertical_min = "-0.925";
  :geospatial_vertical_max = "18.564";
  :geospatial_vertical_units = "m";
  :geospatial_vertical_positive = "up";
  :time_coverage_start = "1985";
  :time_coverage_end = "2050";
  :experiment = "highres-future";
}
```

---

This is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MissingSpatialDimensionError              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 1
----> 1 meanSurgeLevel = meanSurgeLevel.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim = 'station_x_coordinate',
      2                                                      y_dim = 'station_y_coordinate')

File ~/.virtualenvs/VE/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rioxarray/rioxarray.py:858, in XRasterBase.set_spatial_dims(self, x_dim, y_dim, inplace)
    856     data_obj.rio._x_dim = x_dim
    857 else:
--> 858     raise MissingSpatialDimensionError(
    859         f"x dimension ({x_dim}) not found.{_get_data_var_message(data_obj)}"
    860     )
    861 if y_dim in data_obj.dims:
    862     data_obj.rio._y_dim = y_dim

MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension (station_x_coordinate) not found. Data variable: return_mean_surge_level
```

---

Comment: As you have surmised, station_x_coordinate and station_y_coordinate are not dimension coordinates for gridded data. Instead it seems that your example dataset contains station data for 43119 separate locations, and those two coordinate variables specify the individual lon and lat coordinates of each individual station. It mystifies me why the global metadata for the file says that the data are "featureType = "timeSeries"", or have you subsetted a single timestep out of a much larger dataset?

Comment: @R.Schmunk I got this file using an API, from [Climate Copernicus](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-water-level-change-indicators-cmip6?tab=form) so maybe the system automatically subsets a part of a larger database, I don't know. But yes, it is somehow unexpected to me, so I'm still learning what is the most convenient way of exploring this dataset.

Comment: I have downloaded similar scenarios from Copernicus Marine Data (eg. global temperatures) and the files are quite different (and, closer to what one would expect, for instance the grids are evenly-spaced, the coordinates are **dimension coordinates**,  etc.)

Comment: There is some variability in format when you download from that server. I've had two people ping me in the last week because they had downloaded from there (albeit a different download page) and they received gridded GRIB data, but it was unreadable by my software apparently because of unexpected flag settings in the files.